# How should i fix with ng-invalid and ng-pristine in angular validation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a issue about angular validation.

My case point:

1. I have 2 textfields and 1 button in a form.
2. When page load, the button is by ng-disabled with ng-invalid status.
3. Then type something text in a textfield, the button ng-disabled to unlock.
4. [Problem] When i clear all text in a textfield such as delete key with keyboard, the button ng-disabled not to unlock status.
5. If not use 「required」with textfield.

I already put in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uyx1swu3/3/)

```
<div ng-controller="validationCtrl">

    <form name="xyzForm" novalidate>

    <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        ng-model="xname"
        ng-class="{'has-error': xyzForm.name.$invalid && !xyzForm.name.$pristine}"
    />
    <input
        type="number"
        name="age"
        ng-model="xage"
        ng-class="{'has-error': xyzForm.age.$invalid && !xyzForm.age.$pristine && xyzForm.age.$dirty}"
    />

    <div>
       <button ng-click="submit()" ng-disabled="xyzForm.$invalid || xyzForm.$pristine">Submit</button>
       <span>invalid : {{xyzForm.$invalid}}</span>
       <span>pristine : {{xyzForm.$pristine}}</span>
    </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I consider you don't want to user  "Required" Attribute for both textfield and as below you can use

```
<div ng-app="appX">

<div ng-controller="validationCtrl">
                    <form name="xyzForm" novalidate>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="name"
                            ng-model="xname"
                            ng-class="{'has-error': xyzForm.name.$invalid && !xyzForm.name.$pristine}"
                        />
                        <input
                            type="number"
                            name="age"
                            ng-model="xage"
                            ng-class="{'has-error': xyzForm.age.$invalid && !xyzForm.age.$pristine && xyzForm.age.$dirty}"
                        />
            <div>
                                    <button ng-click="submit()" ng-disabled="(xyzForm.$invalid || xyzForm.$pristine) || !xage || xname
==''">Submit</button>
            <span>invalid : {{xyzForm.$invalid}}</span>
            <span>pristine : {{xyzForm.$pristine}}</span>
            </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks your suggestion . but my target is ONE of the textfield, so how do i improve your answer ?